# How to initialize variable in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have this sample code:

```
val someCondition = true
case class SampleClass (source: String)

val sample: SampleClass

if (someCondition)
  sample = new SampleClass("Some String")
else
  sample = new SampleClass("Other String")
```

I want to define a val argument and initialize it based on some condition. but I can't figure out how to do that.
also, if I change it to `var` I still can't.

Comment: It's idiomatic to treat `if-else`'s in Scala as [expressions, not statements](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scala/Expressions,_Not_Statements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as follows.

```scala
val sample: SampleClass = {
  if (someCondition) new SampleClass("Some String")
  else new SampleClass("Other String")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Scala `if` is an expression, which means it evaluates to some value, hence you can do the following:

```
val sample = if (someCondition) new SampleClass("Some String")
             else new SampleClass("Other String")
```